# Escape_javascript problem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a set of dependent dropdown menus on my user/edit page.  The user selects the parent dropdown, which then limits the selections available in the child dropdown.  The user can add multiple additional sets of parent/child dropdowns.  Product is the parent.  Variety is the child.

This all works great unless a variety is entered into the database that includes double quotes.  When that happens, it breaks the javascript and the trigger to render the partial doesn't work at all.

Single quotes do not cause this problem, nor do any other characters that I've tried.  So this problem is specific to double quotes.  I thought that escape_javascript was the answer here, but I've tried placing it in many different places in the code and nothing has worked.  It's very possible that I just don't know exactly where the helper and it's parenthesis are supposed to go.

The api documentation is terrible.  It says escape_javascript().  That's not helpful for me.  Similarly, there isn't much clear guidance online.  I've searched for hours.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

Users#edit.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'season', :collection => @user.seasons %>
```

Users#_season.html.erb

```
<% fields_for prefix, season do |season_form| -%>
  <%= error_messages_for :season, :object => season %>
    Product: <%= season_form.collection_select :product_id, Product.find(:all, :order =>'name'), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Product"}, {:onchange => "collectionSelected(this);"} %>

    <% varieties = season.product ? season.product.varieties : Variety.all %>
    <%= season_form.select :variety_id, options_from_collection_for_select(varieties, :id, :name, season.variety_id), :prompt => "This is optional" %>
```

Javascripts#dynamic_varieties.js.erb

```
var varieties = new Array();
<% for variety in @varieties -%>
  varieties.push (new Array (<%=h variety.product_id %>, "<%=h variety.name %>", <%=h variety.id %>));
<% end -%>


function collectionSelected(e) {
  product_id = e.getValue();
  options = e.next(1).options;
  options.length = 1;
  varieties.each(function(variety) {
    if (variety[0] == product_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(variety[1], variety[2]);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just doing some escaping wrong (and that rails does it correctly), you could try something like:

```
var varieties = <%= @varieties.map { |v| [v.product_id, h(v.name), v.id] }.to_json %>
```